# "No data" when submitting contact form?

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Using a small contact form, however when the form is submitted/sent, I'm getting a "No data" message.

---

```
<form method="post" action="mail.php">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Name*" name="name" required>
   <input type="email" placeholder="Email*" name="email" required>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="subject">
   <textarea placeholder="Message"  name="message" required></textarea>
   <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit">
</form>
```

---

The PHP:

```
<?php

// variable
$fromemail = 'any_site@my_site_com'; // from mail
$to = "marygsheehan@yahoo.ie"; // to mail

// 
// check data
if (!isset($_POST["fields"])) {
die("No data"); 
}

$fields = $_POST["fields"];

if( empty($fields['name']) ) { 
die("No name"); 
}

if( empty($fields['email']) ) { 
die("No email"); 
}

if (!empty( $fields['code'] ) ) {
die("ok"); 
}



$subject = "Site mail: " . $fields['subject'];
// subject massege
$subject = '=?utf-8?Q?'."\"".urlencode($subject)."\"".'?=';
$subject= str_replace("%","=",$subject);
$subject = str_replace("+","_",$subject);

// content massage
$name = $name ? $name : 'unknown';
$from   = 'Mail from'."<".$fromemail.">";
$mess = $mess ? $mess : 'unknown';
$message = "<b>Client name: </b> " . $fields['name'] . "<br>";
$message .= "<b>Client email: </b> " . $fields['email'] . "<br>";
/*$message .= "<b>Client phone: </b> ".$site."<br>";*/
$message .= "<b>Subject: </b> " . $fields['subject'] . "<br>";
$message .= "<b>Text:</b>\n" . $fields['text'] . "<br>";

$message .= "Sent: ".strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S");
// end content massage


$headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: Site Mail <" . $fromemail . ">\r\n"; 

if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
print 'ok';
} else {
print 'email not senta';
}

?>
```

---

I've been staring at it so long it's a blur, so it's probably a silly mistake. Any help appreciated?

Comment: this is because you don't have any input with name `fields` so `$_POST['fileds']` is not set

Comment: in your form no value are there with name `fields` that's why `if (!isset($_POST["fields"])) {
die("No data"); 
}` is always true and you are getting nothing

Comment: just check for `$_POST['submit']`, then assign entire `$fields = $_POST`;

Answer (score 1):

There is no input field in the form with name `fields`

You need to access them directly like this

```
$_POST['your_input_name_declared_in_form']
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it as follow

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     $fields = $_POST;
     if( empty($fields['name']) ) { 
         die("No name"); 
     }

     if( empty($fields['email']) ) { 
         die("No email"); 
     }

     if (!empty( $fields['code'] ) ) {
           die("ok"); 
     }

 }
```

Comment: its not a good practice to check submit button values. directly checking the posted values will be more good and effective

Comment: it is obvious when user click on form and leave all input blank then only $_POST['submit'] is set.

Comment: and that's why i tell what i said?

Comment: I tried this suggestion and it's giving me the 'message sent' message, however it's not going through to the email? 

I didn't write this code by the way, I'm just trying to help somebody fix it.

Comment: What do you mean? sorry, I'm not too familiar with this.

Comment: put your email code inside `if($_POST['submit'])` like Mawia HL's answer

Comment: you are on local server ?

Comment: No! you can see the website live itself at marygsheehan.com

Comment: check spam...may be email is received there